# How to install pip without sudo or wget or brew or easy_install?

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, sudo

I am trying to download pip but I don't have sudo access. I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
**kwargs
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/var/folders/h3/mg0jxd6x7v9gmrg89kcwxbfcpm025t/T/tmp0PONb0/pip.zip/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

I've tried to go through many other solutions, but they each require sudo, wget, brew, and/or easy_install, etc. Can someone provide the steps I should take to download pip without these?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this will help ..https://forcecarrier.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/installing-pip-virutalenv-in-sudo-free-way/

Comment: This solution requires wget

Answer (score 0):

Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).

Create and activate virtualenv and install your packages in virualenv. You won't require sudo access.

Comment: I get this error: 

   ' File "virtualenv.py", line 1
        <html><body>You are being <a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py">redirected</a>.</body></html>
    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: easiest and best way to use vistualenv is via virtualwrapper http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Installation of virtualwrapper involves using sudo and/or pip though, which I don't have

Answer (score 0):

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

You can download the .py file and run it to install pip.

Comment: So install it with virtualenv like Arun has said. I think you don't have another solution.